# How to Connect to Documentum via .net application?

Tags: .net, documentum

I need to use documentum for inline editing of documents via .net application.I am completely new to this documentum.Is it possible to do this?.It would be really helpful if someone helps me on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like they have a REST API. A .NET app can of course use that.

Comment: If possible can you please provide some websites where I can find more about this?

Comment: I don't know anything about it. I just meant that at minimum you could call the REST API because they have a REST API or so the first page of a Google search revealed. This question is really too broad. You should read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consume documentum DFS webservices from .NET application. Please check below urls

https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-2214

https://community.emc.com/thread/83150?start=0&tstart=0